# class-validator relational validation with custom error messages

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

so I was building an API where by user gives us `type` and `value` in the request body, `type` could be `CNIC, EMAIL, MOBILE`

Now based on the `type` I have to validate the value like if `EMAIL` is valid or if `MOBILE` is valid etc.

So as we can see that `value` field depends on the `type` field to validate it.

I need a way to handle this using `class-validator` `validationPipe`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So at first I quickly opened the docs and started looking up for advance usage and I came to know that custom decorator would definitely help me and it did using bellow example.

`validate-value-by-type.decorator.ts`

```
import {
  registerDecorator,
  ValidationOptions,
  ValidationArguments,
  isEmail,
} from 'class-validator';
import { CA_DetailsTypes } from './models';

export function ValidateByAliasType(
  property: string,
  validationOptions?: ValidationOptions,
) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
  return function (object: Object, propertyName: string) {
    registerDecorator({
      name: 'validateByAliasType',
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName: propertyName,
      constraints: [property],
      options: validationOptions,
      validator: {
        validate(value: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
          const [relatedPropertyName] = args.constraints;
          const relatedValue = (args.object as any)[relatedPropertyName];
          if (relatedValue === CA_DetailsTypes.EMAIL) {
            return isEmail(value) && value.length > 5 && value.length <= 99;
          }
          if (relatedValue === CA_DetailsTypes.CNIC) {
            return value.length === 13;
          }
          if (relatedValue === CA_DetailsTypes.MOBILE) {
            return value.length === 11;
          }
          if (relatedValue === CA_DetailsTypes.TXT) {
            return value.length > 3 && value.length <= 99;
          }
          return false;
        },
      },
    });
  };
}
```

`client.request.dto.ts`

```
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { IsEnum, IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

export enum CA_DetailsTypes {
  'CNIC' = 'CNIC',
  'MOBILE' = 'MOBILE',
  'EMAIL' = 'EMAIL',
  'TXT' = 'TXT',
}

export class CA_FetchDetails_DTO {
  @ApiProperty({
    example: 'MOBILE',
    type: 'enum',
    enum: CA_DetailsTypes,
  })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEnum(CA_DetailsTypes)
  type: CA_DetailsTypes;

  @ApiProperty({ example: '03070000002' })
  @ValidateByAliasType('type')
  value: string;
}
```

So with the above example I'm successfully able to validate `value` by `type`, but still I'm unable to customize the error message based on the `type` .

So after a day of research I lose all my hope and decided to use another library for this complex validation and I did so but there was a drawback with that library and I ended up coming back to the `class-validator` and after a lot of research I found a way to customize the error message based on the `type`.

So here is the code for customizing error message based on the `type` and I used `defaultMessage()` to customize it.

`validate-value-by-type.decorator.ts`

```
import {
  registerDecorator,
  ValidationOptions,
  ValidationArguments,
  isEmail,
} from 'class-validator';
import { CA_DetailsTypes } from './models';

export function ValidateByAliasType(
  property: string,
  validationOptions?: ValidationOptions,
) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
  return function (object: Object, propertyName: string) {
    registerDecorator({
      name: 'validateByAliasType',
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName: propertyName,
      constraints: [property],
      options: validationOptions,
      validator: {
        validate(value: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
          const [relatedPropertyName] = args.constraints;
          const relatedValue = (args.object as any)[relatedPropertyName];
          if (relatedValue === CA_DetailsTypes.EMAIL) {
            return isEmail(value) && value.length > 5 && value.length <= 99;
          }
          if (relatedValue === CA_DetailsTypes.CNIC) {
            return value.length === 13;
          }
          if (relatedValue === CA_DetailsTypes.MOBILE) {
            return value.length === 11;
          }
          if (relatedValue === CA_DetailsTypes.TXT) {
            return value.length > 3 && value.length <= 99;
          }
          return false;
        },
        defaultMessage(args?: ValidationArguments) {
          const [relatedPropertyName] = args.constraints;
          const relatedValue = (args.object as any)[relatedPropertyName];
          switch (relatedValue) {
            case CA_DetailsTypes.EMAIL:
              return 'Please enter valid email!';

            case CA_DetailsTypes.MOBILE:
              return 'Please enter valid mobile!';

            case CA_DetailsTypes.CNIC:
              return 'Please enter valid CNIC!';

            default:
              return 'Invalid value!';
          }
        },
      },
    });
  };
}
```

And finally it's done!